# C# how to send scanner string to form 2

Tags: c#

I am creating an app with two forms.
On my main form1 I have a scanner that gets connected through a button.
I have a text box on my form2 and in this text box is where I want the information that gets scanned to go here. 
there is no textbox on my form1.

I cant seem to figure out how to do this I was wondering if any one had any tips.

Thank you

---

This is the code in form 1 that allows me to set up the scanner

---

```
    /// Event Handler for Scanner Setup Button
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void scannerFormBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //If the Button is yellow , disconnect the hand scanner 
            if (scannerBTN.BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
            {
                scanner.ReadStringArrived -= new ReadStringArrivedHandler(OnReadStringArrived);
                scanner.Disconnect();
                scanner = null;
                scannerFormBTN.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                this.scannerFormBTN.Text = "Setup Hand Scanner";
                MessageBox.Show("Hand Scanner Disconnected.", "Alert");
            }
            //If scanner is not connected
            else
            {
                Setupscanner scannerForm = new Setupscanner(); //Instantiate the Scanner Form
                //Show the form. DialogResult = yes if Scanner is connected successfully.
                DialogResult connection_successfull = scannerForm.ShowDialog();
                if (connection_successfull == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    this.scanner = scannerForm.sys; //Set the Local Hand Scanner variable to the successfully connected scanner
                    if (scanner.IsConnected)
                    {
                        scanner.ReadStringArrived += new ReadStringArrivedHandler(OnReadStringArrived); //Register Read String event.
                        scannerFormBTN.Text = "Hand Scanner Connected. Click to Disconnect";
                        scannerBTN.BackColor = Color.LightGreen; //Change the color of the Hand Scanner Button
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("There was an error. Exception reads : \n\n " + ex.Message, "Error"); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event that gets fired when string arrives from a connected   hand scanner
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    private void OnReadStringArrived(Object sender, ReadStringArrivedEventArgs args)
    {
        SetSerNumber(args.ReadString);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used to set the Serial Number to the incoming Scanner String
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="msg"></param>
    private void SetSerNumber(string msg)
    {
        //If the event is fired on a different thread than the control was created
        if (Part_Code_Text_Box.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetSerialNumber S = new SetSerialNumber(SetSerNumber);
            this.Invoke(S, new object[] { msg }); //Invoke the delegate S on the current thread
        }
        else
        {
            Part_Code_Text_Box.Text = msg.Trim();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Property Or Field in Form 2 ..let's Call It StringFromScanner For Now .
When You Want To Show another From u will most likely Create an Object From it ...Set This Object's StringFromScanner To The String You Have ..and When You Open The Second Form Will Have The value of the string in this property and u can assign it to any control

In Form 1

```
Form2 objectfromform2 = new Form2();
objectfromform2.StringFromScanner = MyString;
objectfromform2.Show();
```

in Form 2

```
MytextBox.Text = StringFromScanner
```

You Can Also Forget About The Property and Use The Constructor To Achive The Same Result